# RibbonTab Error

Tags: c#, wpf

I am newbie C# (WPF) and I learn how to use Ribbon Control.

this is error message The property 'Label' was not found in type 'RibbonTab
and this is the Code:

```
<r:RibbonWindow x:Class="WpfApplication2.Editor"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
         mc:Ignorable="d" >
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <r:Ribbon Title="WPF Ribbon - Document 1" x:Name="ribbon" />
    <r:RibbonTab Label="Home"/>
    <r:RibbonTab Label="Insert"/>
    <r:RibbonTab Label="Help"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that there's no `Label` property. You're looking for the `Header` property which sets, well, the Header.

From the [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbontab.aspx)

> Header: Gets or sets the item that labels the control.  (Inherited
>   from HeaderedItemsControl.)